# How to run a program from terminal, which allows to close terminal after the program is open?

Tags: command-line

Could someone remind me how do I run application through the terminal, which allow me to close the terminal after the program is open. I totally forgot how to do this. Please let me know.

Comment: There's a variety of methods you could use. The disown command is popular, but I've never been a fan of it. Personally, I prefer to use a multiplexer like Tmux, although screen would work as well.

Comment: This as not been answered. Is not the Answer am looking for. If it was I would have not posted this, as I have seen those posts before.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think this Q is duplicate. I think that the OP wants a command ***which allows to close terminal after the program is open***.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu and `nohup` doesn't?

Comment: @user242294 can you explain exactly your need. it seems confusing for the community

Comment: A few months ago, my lecturer showed me a command that actually does it all, like with nohup you still have to press ctrl-c to skip to the next line. My lecturer showed me one that does everything. I was able to open an txt editor and then actually carry on with the same window.

Comment: @user242294 The confusion is about: do you want that the terminal to be closed manually or automatically?

Comment: @Braiam `nohup` doesn't close the terminal ;)

Comment: @user242294 with nohup you don't need to press ctrl+c to skip to the next line. simply click enter and see that have just run the program (like firefox) and you still have control on the terminal. Try it

Answer (score 6):

```
(command &) && exit
```

Example:

```
(firefox &) && exit
```

Comment: If I close the terminal, firefox will be lost.

Comment: @Braiam Which terminal are you using?!? The terminal is already closed when firefox is opened. :)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu the OP mentioned that he want to close the terminal manually

Comment: also, instead of firefox use gedit.

Comment: @kamil Wheeere?

Comment: @Braiam No matter what I use, the behavior is the same: the new program is opening, when the terminal is closing.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu he said "allow me to close the terminal"

Comment: @kamil And where is ***manually***?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Ok I asked the OP and let him decide if he means manually or automatically

Comment: `command &` run the command as background program and close the terminal or anything you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way:

```
nohup (command) &> /dev/null &
```

example:

```
nohup firefox &> /dev/null &
```

Edit: the "&> /dev/null &" redirects the output of nohup such that you do not have logs (nohup.out) See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/how-to-make-nohup-not-create-any-output-files-and-so-not-eat-all-space

[image]

Then I can close terminal without a warning message either by the `exit` command or by clicking the x on the terminal window

Comment: Added information to prevent "nohup.out" log files. An alternate to nohup is disown or running your applications in screen, depending on what you want to do. screen tends to work well with ssh.

Comment: the OP said: "allow me to close the terminal" not "close terminal automatically"

Comment: `>&` is not a syntax error.

Comment: @Olli then why you did the edit. by the way both works

Comment: I didn't edit it, rolled back the edit by @terdon

Comment: @Olli yes, please roll back again. `&>` means redirect both standard error and standard output, it is shorthand for `2>&1 >`, `>&` means redirect to a file called `&` which, since `&` is a special character for bash, will give an error for most commands and works only by chance on the `nohup`. That is not a good reason to keep a syntax error in an answer. Compare `ls >& /dev/null` and `ls &> /dev/null`.

Comment: @Olli also, while this is most certainly a syntax error, it does seem to "work" in the specific case of nohup when running in any of bash,zsh, tcsh or csh but fails in dash, ` ksh and fish. More details in my [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118303/22222) on [unix.se].